# Why do I have a 2 kill streak?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

I got two kills and I'm notified with a logo that appears on screen. It's also written "Recon"

I don't understand; I didn't chose the Hardline perk. My kill streak rewards are given when I get 3, 4, and 5 kill streak.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I discovered what happened.

I unblocked the specialist kill streak. By default when you got 2 kill streak, you get the perk `Recon`

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you got another kill and weren't aware of it, (sometimes mines explode and give you a kill, etc) or that one of your kills was actually a double kill.  A 3-kill streak might unlock UAV Recon, which would explain the icon and the notification.

Also, "Recon" is one of the perks, so it's possible that you unlocked some Recon-related challenge, such as Recon Pro.

It's hard to say based on the info you provided, but those are my top two explanations.  There's no "Recon" for 2 kills without Hardline as far as I'm aware.

Comment: It sounds like he's using the Specialist kill streak set. You only need 2 kills to unlock the first additional perk.

Answer (score 0):

Note that...

- planting or defusing a bomb (depending on the game-mode)
- shooting down or destroying enemys killstreaks
- and some other things

also count for kill-streaks—maybe you defused a bomb wich counted as your third "kill".